# How to apply styles dynamically from startIndex to endIndex on strings that change positions

Tags: android, algorithm, android-jetpack-compose

I will try to be very clear in explaining this.

I am fetching some strings from an API like this:

```
@TEST^1@ this is a string for $@test@$
```

Every special character in this definition means something. `@text@` means text between `@` is `bolded` style, `$` is for italic, and so on. I create the following `enum` defining the `regex` and the corresponding `style`

```
enum class RegexStyleEnum(val regex: Regex, val style: SpanStyle) {
    BOLD(
        Regex("(?<!\\\\\\\\)@(.*?)(?<!\\\\\\\\)@"),
        SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
    ),
    ITALIC(
        Regex("(?<!\\\\\\\\)\\$(.*?)(?<!\\\\\\\\)\\$"),
        SpanStyle(fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic)
    ),
    SUPERSCRIPT(
        Regex("(?<!\\\\\\\\)\\^(\\d)"),
        SpanStyle(baselineShift = BaselineShift.Superscript)
    ),
    UNDERLINE(
        Regex("(?<!\\\\\\\\)#(.*?)(?<!\\\\\\\\)#"),
        SpanStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline)
    )
}
```

Now, I created an algorithm (that is not correct) that does this:

1. Iterate through all the `regex` and find all the matches inside a string.
2. Order all the matches ascending by the first position of the character found in regex.
3. Iterate through results from step 2, apply only the regex I am iterating & replace the old value with the new value and apply the style. Replace the old string with the new one

The real problem:

If I have a word with markup like this: `$@test@$` (length of 8, chars from pos 0..7)
The algorithm would take first the `$$` and the resulting string would be `@test@`. The style is `Italic` from index 0 to index 5.

Now the second iteration would take `@@` and the resulting string would be `test` (correct) and the style would be `Bold` from index 0 to 3.

When these styles would apple to the word, the program would give `IndexOutOfBounds`.

The example is for a simple case with only 1 word, I have sentences with multiple wards that need to have a style.

I know there would be a better solution which I haven't yet figured out but I'm losing my mind on this for over a week.

Comment: What do you intend to do with resulting string? If your purpose is to show it somewhere in a TextView maybe it's make sense to simply convert your special characters to HTML tags?

Comment: Jetpack Compose doesn't support officially HTML formatting.

Comment: @bylazy I already have it with html tags, but there is no way of showing HTML text in Jetpack compose, or I didn't find any.